# MS SQL Server - Using multiple physical partition

Tags: sql-server

I'm facing this problem: basically we got a 10TB SQL DB we need to import in a new MS SQL Server.
In the new server we have a max allowance of 3TB per drive partition, so I'm wondering how is the best approach to configure properly the server.
Is possible to partition the DB while importing the 10TB?
Any idea or suggestion is much more than appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Does the database have one large data file or are there multiple? One option is to split to multiple files before the move, if the database is still currently on a working sql server. When you say you have a 'max allowance of 3TB per drive partition'... what do you mean? Who/what is enforcing this maximum?

Comment: Thx, some additional remarks: I cannot change partition limits for the new server hosting the SQL DB, so I cannot merge this physical partition.My question is about to get if there's a way to configure MS SQL itself to use 3+3+3+3 (12TB over 4 partition) in order to have 10 TB I need for data I need to import.

Comment: Yes that is certainly possible. Read up on files on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx